# multiply two columns from two different tables and group them together

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have two tables in MySQL which are sale and material details.
I want to calculate the profit I made by selling items which is
`profit = (total) -(qty* landedcost)`
Here is the structure of the two tables:
[image: sale and materialdetails table]

This is the query

```
SELECT sale.name ,sale.total-(sale.qty * materialdetails.landingcost) AS 
result
FROM sale JOIN materialdetails
on sale.id = materialdetails.id
GROUP BY sale.name,result;
```

the result i get :
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQA7p.png)

I want something like this

```
  name          result
  A4             5000
 Computer        40000
 Flash memory    1000
 Headphone       22000
 Mobile         35000
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sum the result and group by `sale.name` only, something like this:

```
SELECT sale.name ,sum(sale.total-(sale.qty * materialdetails.landingcost)) AS 
result
FROM sale JOIN materialdetails
on sale.id = materialdetails.id
GROUP BY sale.name;
```

Explanation: if you group by two fields `GROUP BY sale.name,result` you will get one line for all records that have the same `sale.name` *and* `result`, so for instance

```
name     result

Computer 10000
Computer 25000
```

are two different lines and they are not grouped together as one.

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my day but what if I want to sum the whole result i.e the sum of sum?

Comment: @smp Add [`with rollup`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to get a total while keeping the detail sums. To just get the total, use `SELECT sum(...) FROM ...`